# Check if item exists in Firestore and save it otherwise (array)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Before inserting item to Firestore, I need to check if item is already in database or save it otherwise.

I'm using this code:

```
for (let item of items) {
    db.collection('collection')
      .where('property', '==', item)
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
          if (snap.size === 0) {
              db.collection('collection').add(somethingToInsert);
          }
     });
}
```

Is there better way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: It would be clear if you put your firestore structure image in this.

Comment: @ToraCode Collection has this structure: `collection: { autoID: { link: string (URL), status: string } }`.

Comment: where is your `property` field?

Comment: @ToraCode Property field is link.